# How to manually render a part of a django form

Tags: django, forms, templates

I actually render a django form with the following code into template.html :

```
<form action="{% url "demande_create_form" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

One of the field is rendered with a checkbox widget, with a lot of values, so I would like to put them in a table.

Is there a way to do this without manually render the whole form ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use following lines (with their corresponding errors) :

```
<form action="{% url "demande_create_form" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <li>
    {{ form.nameOfField1 }}
    {{ form.nameOfField1.errors }}
  </li>
  <li>
    {{ form.nameOfField2 }}
    {{ form.nameOfField2.errors }}
  </li>
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

Here is the doc for 1.6 : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template

Also, as you have many fields, you can use some code like this :

```
<form action="{% url "demande_create_form" %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
    <li>
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</form>
```

Of course, you can use anything else than `<li>`.

Comment: I have near 30 fields in my form. If I use this solution, I have to write them ALL, from  {{ form.nameOfField1 }} to  {{ form.nameOfField30}}, isnt'it ?
My question was about manual rendering only the checkboxed field, which is alone.

Comment: You can choose to render firldd 1,2.26 and 30 if you want. You dont have to render all.

Comment: If you want to render them all, yes, you have to write all 30 of them, or use a method like you did before : `{{ form.as_p }}`. Note that you can set a class to each attribute of your form (in forms.py) if you need to apply special styling.

Comment: My bad, just saw this, you can actually loop over the fields : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields. Added to answer.

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent : Edit, just saw your second comment.
Could you tell me more about setting classes to attributes ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances. Code like : `forms.CharField(
                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'special'}))`